# Issue displaying data in C++

Tags: c++

```
// AnnualSalesReport.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



int main() 
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("S:\\(Documents)\\SalesAssociateAnnualReport - Associates.csv");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run the code above, it doesn't output. I added the "Unable to open file" in the event if it doesn't work and clearly it doesn't. Its a very simple task and I cannot find the issue after looking on other forums and SO. Anything helps.

Comment: Are you sure about `(Documents)` in that file path? Can you open that exact path from the cmd shell?? E.g. `type "S:\(Documents)\SalesAssociateAnnualReport - Associates.csv"`

Comment: the file may be empty

Comment: I just cropped the file directory just for the sake of the post. The full directory is ("S:\\LIU Post 2020 - 2021 (Documents)\\Semester 1 (2020 - 2021)\\CS 111\\SalesAssociateAnnualReport - Associates.csv");

Comment: @Childish And do you receive any results with `type`, in particular when runing it from a different root, e.g. write `d:`, and then `type "S:\LIU Post 2020 - 2021 (Documents)\Semester 1 (2020 - 2021)\CS 111\SalesAssociateAnnualReport - Associates.csv"`?

Comment: @Childish Try a different path, one that isn't so complicated. That way you'll find out if the error is that particular path or something else.

Comment: I just hovered over the file and copied the path, so I don't know what else could be the issue now

Comment: @Childish The path syntax suggests you are in Windows. Are you running the program "elevated" (a.k.a. as administrator), and does it work any differently if you run it at a regular `cmd` command prompt?